# Botones escalonados en vez de justificados a la derecha

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, bootstrap-5

No consigo que los botones me salgan alineados a la derecha, utilizo `bootstrap5`.
La pantalla me queda así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')

<div class="container w-25 border p-4 mt-4">

    <form action="{{ route('todos') }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @if (session('success'))
        <h6 class="alert alert-success"> {{ session('success')}}</h6>
        @endif

        @error('title')
        <h6 class="alert alert-danger"> {{ $message }}</h6>
        @enderror
        <div class="mb-3 text-center">
            <label for="title" class="form-label">Titulo de la tarea</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">Crear nueva tarea</button>


    </form>

    <div>
        @foreach ($todos as $todo)
        <div class="row py-1">
            <div class="col-md-9 d-flex align-items-center">
                <a href="{{ route('todos-edit', ['id' => $todo->id]) }}"> {{ $todo->title }}</a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <form action="{{ route('todos-destroy', [$todo->id]) }}" method="POST">
                    @method('DELETE')
                    @csrf
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm d-flex justify-content-end">Eliminar</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Por favor, hay alguien que me pueda ayudar.

Gracias

Comment: Es porque el `@endforeach` está mal posicionado, lo escribiste una línea antes de cerrar el `div` donde creas la fila.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias, me ha funcionado, llevaba tiempo mirándolo y solo me fijaba en las clases y no en el @endforeach. Eres un crack.